# Spring MVC and JSP. Basic steps

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am starting with Spring MVC, but something is going wrong because I am getting 404 error with the message "The requested resource is not available." Searching for few hours and trying different things didn't help, so I decided to ask help from you guys.

I have an index.jsp where I want to have a link which will invoke the method in my controller and will return hello.jsp.

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="${"test"}">Click to press hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

By clicking to this link I assume that I should come to my MessageController:

```
package main.java.service;

//imports...

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class MessageController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getThis(Map<String, String> map) {
        map.put("message", "Hello World!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

According to my understanding it should happen because I marked the package of my controller is including in servlet-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc             http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

   <mvc:annotation-driven />
   <context:component-scan base-package="main.java.service"/>

   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
   </bean>
 </beans>
```

And then finally there is a web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

    <display-name>SpringWebConfiguration</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

So, according to that I should get a hello.jsp file with the message Hello World! but instead I get a 404 error with the message "The requested resource is not available." Would be nice if someone could find an issue here.

Here is my hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII" pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>Here there is a message: ${message}</body>
</html>
```

This is the working repo: https://github.com/vladt89/fsboard

Comment: The `servlet-config.xml` should be loaded by the `DispatcherSerlet`. It currently doesn't get loaded by any component. The `context-param` should instead be an `init-param` of the `servlet`.

Comment: That could be right, however, unfortunately still I cannot make it to work. I have added         `<init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>` to my servlet, but still get an error of _The resource is not available_ when I go to [http://localhost:8080/test].

Comment: try with /projectname/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `web.xml` as

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

<display-name>SpringWebConfiguration</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

or you can just ignore `<init-param>` by:

**Renaming** your `servlet-config.xml` to `spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml`
when `<init-param>` is not present `Name of the Spring configuration file` should be same as the `servlet-name` which used in `web.xml` with a tailing `-servlet`.

And definitely you need to put your `hello.jsp` inside `WEB-INF` folder as you have defined in the view resolver as

```
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
```

so it will look for the `jsp` files inside the `WEB-INF` folder

---

**Update** : I have fork your code and tested in my environment.

The Code which causing this problem you haven't post in you question.... too bad.
**Add `@Component` in both in  your `MessageService` and `MessageServiceImpl`**

```
@Component
public interface MessageService {

    void createMessage(String message);

    Collection<String> fetchAllMessages();
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {
    private Collection<String> messageLibrary = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    public void createMessage(String message) {
        messageLibrary.add(message);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<String> fetchAllMessages() {
        return messageLibrary;
    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds pretty good, but still no luck. Maybe you could check the repo where I made changes (https://github.com/vladt89/fsboard). I am just thinking if there is some method to debug it because it is not super handy to change something and then restart the server plus the main bad thing is that the message is always the same. Could it be some other thing which influence this? I am starting to think if I start the server wrong, but at least index.jsp file I can see.

Comment: i have tested the updated  fix in my environment and its working fine. Let me know  and please let me know it the problem is solved. @VladimirTikhomirov

Answer (score 1):

Check your url in href reaches your controller and Is hello.jsp available inside WEB-INF folder?

Comment: That is the problem that it does not reach the controller. The structure is that in _web/WEB-INF_ I have _servlet-config.xml_ and _web.xml_ and these two _jsp_ files I have just in _web_ folder.

Answer (score 0):

in `index.jsp` your link seems to be bad. you may want to change the anchor tag to:

```
<a href="test">Click to press hello</a>
```

Comment: I think that the link is correct. Anyway, I try to go to [http://localhost:8080/test] and there I get an error 404 with the message _The resource is not available_, so it seems that my _servlet-config.xml_ where I include my _MessageController_ by _context:component-scan_ is not loaded.

Comment: where is the hello.jsp present in your webapp?

Comment: It is placed in _web_ folder.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding suggestions from [Annamalai Thangaraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2314379/annamalai-thangaraj) and [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis).

1. You need to initialize the context in web.xml.
2. You need to place the `hello.jsp` in `WEB-INF` folder. This is because the view resolver you have configured is looking for the `hello.jsp` in `WEB-INF`

Comment: 1. It is in.
2. That might be true, but still it doesn't help. If I do that I also don't have an opportunity to go to hello.jsp. And when I try WEB-INF/hello.jsp I start to get unavailable resource message for this page as well.

Comment: Plus, if I change my path to _/_ it is still the same situation. 

Check the repo: https://github.com/vladt89/fsboard Maybe it will be easier from there.

Comment: in MessageController keep the return statement as:return "hello"; and the hello.jsp has to be moved to WEB-INF/hello.jsp . That is where view resolver will look for it. you will not be able to do a http://localhost:8080/WEB-INF/hello.jsp . The only way to load that jsp will be http://localhost:8080/test .

Comment: I also see that in init params of `web.xml` the path of the spring context file should be starting with a '`/`'.

Comment: Just to explain what is happening internally, when request comes for `/test`, spring hands the request to `MessageController.getThis()`. this method is does the processing and returns the view that has to be shown. Spring container hands the request to View resolver bean that is configured. The view resolver you have configured just takes the string returned by Controller and prefixes "`WEB-INF/`" and suffixes "`.jsp`". Hence Spring will look for this jsp in "`WEB-INF/hello.jsp`". The jsp will be executed and the response text will be returnd to the browser or client.